# Convert a short DateTime string with date and time to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, xamarin.android

Having trouble with my Android project here trying to convert a string of DateTime into an actual DateTime object.
here's the code I wrote:

```
string strDateTime = reminder.Date + " " + ((ReminderByTime)reminder).ReminderTime;
userDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH/mm", null);
```

While running the problem I've checked the values and they do coordinate:
[image: screen shot of debug window]

How can I fix this?

Comment: "*while running the problem I've checked the values and they do coordinate*" No, they do not. Check again. :-) Hint: Look at what's between the hours and the minutes.

Comment: @Heinzi wow lmao been on it for 20 min or so thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it happens to all of us once we work on the same piece of code for too long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see **Exact** in the name of the `ParseExact()` method, *it means it!* The method is notoriously unforgiving about small typos or format variations.

In this case, the time portion of the format string uses a different separator than the actual value. `HH/mm`, which uses a `/`, does not match `18:20`, which uses a colon (`:`).

Therefore your format string needs to look like this:

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
```

---

In the future, I also advise you to avoid posting screen shots of technical information like debugger results. I know of no faster way to attract downvotes to your questions, and it's really **MUCH** better for us to see that kind of information as well-formatted text instead.